# Run a code only once in Uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating a Uwp app where I just have to show the user a one-time notification if a certain condition is matched and one time only.Now the function which does this is defined in another project of type class library n the file check.cs and I call this function in a background task project and in another uwp type project.

Tried Method:

Classic approach:

1. Declared a bool variable say count and initialized value to true.
2. When the condition is matched and notification displayed to set the count to false.So now notification will not show again.

Code : //In class check.cs

```
var one = true;
public static async Task Onetime()
{
    if (x == 2 && one)
    {
        PopToast("Only once");
        one = false;
    }
}
```

Code in app.xaml.cs constructor :

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["one"] = "true";
```

Code inside function :

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
string value = localSettings.Values["one"].ToString();
if(x==2 && value=="true")
{                            
    PopToast("Only once");
    localSettings.Values["one"] = "false";                       
}
```

But the problem it works fine till app is running but when the app is closed and opened again the value of variable is initialized to true again.
Is there any workaround?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe you want to be setting the value to "true" withing the constructor as this will always be setting the value first. You way want to be reading in the value there instead.

Comment: so where should I initialise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're initialising it in a property/field declaraion, so it will always be true. Here's my implementation to check whether or not to sync data on the given device. Checks for null (on first app run), if so, intialises it to what it should be then set app data accordingly. If not, then retrieves the current data and sets the local app info accordingly. I'm certainly not a professional, but this seems to be functioning exactly as intended.

```
object onedrive = localsettings.Values[_dataSyncSetting];
        if (onedrive == null)
        {
            localsettings.Values[_dataSyncSetting] = true;
            _isDataSyncEnabled = true;
            _dataPolicy = _dataSync;
        }
        else
        {
            _isDataSyncEnabled = (Boolean)onedrive;
            _dataPolicy = _isDataSyncEnabled ? _dataSync : _dataLocal;
        }
```

Edit; `_dataSyncSetting` is a `const string` declared in the same class

Answer (score 1):

save the state to local disk by using the applicationdata class. need bit more context

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have updated my answer please check it @DaveSmits

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet *may* be to hold the previous or current state (*depending on how you look at it*) into a config XML file or AppData container.

Please see the following [***documentation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalSettings) for reference to ApplicationDataContainer local setting's storage.

Upon startup of the application, the value can be checked and read in to declare that variable appropriately. Essentially every time the user is notified - immediately after you would want to update that config file to ensure it is known that the user has already been notified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but is there any sample for this or can you give a reference to understand this.@ChrisCruz

Comment: Please see my edit for a link to the appropriate documentation for AppData storage usage.

Comment: I tried this but where do I initialize the value because wherever I initialized it runs again and value is initialized to true.

Comment: Without being able to see all of your code, I can only assume that this would be best initialized upon form load. And the alternatively, you would save the value after the user is alerted or on form close.

Comment: Updated my question with the code I tried.Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize the setting in `App.xaml.cs` each time the application starts.

Add it only once and check whether the setting actually exists in your `Check` class:

```
const string key = "one";
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (x == 2 && !localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
{
    PopToast("Only once");
    localSettings.Values[key] = "false";
}
```